# Hello, Anonymous! How I set the AnonymousUser username in django...auth?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

Please read carefully before you respond with the Django tutorial answers.

I want to put `Hello, {{ request.user.username }}` into a template, and if no user is logged in it should return "Hello, Anonymous". Not "Hello, ".

Imagine my surprise when this test case failed:

```
def test_hello_Anon(self):
    assert 'Anonymous' == auth.models.AnonymousUser().username
```

Does anyone know how to pass it? Preferably without overriding and re-registering the `AnonymousUser` class??

I'm asking because `if` statements are evil.

Comment: Have you considered using a custom context processor?

Comment: I don't know if I have missed something as simple as `auth.model.AnonymousUser.username = "anon"` at file-scope. I considered a custom processor, which is why I added "no overriding & re-registering."

Comment: Basically, I was going to suggest using a custom context processor to hide the template filter than Daniel's example used so your template code be just `{{ username }}`, etc, which doesn't override anything.

Comment: please note the test I asked for help passing.

Comment: I'm not following how leveraging the `default` filter is making your test case pass...

Comment: I explained why I bumped that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has a perfectly usable [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#default) filter:

```
{{ request.user.username|default:"Anonymous" }}
```

Comment: tx - I favorited that to FAQ the `default:` processor technique - even though it's just a hidden `if`. (`if` statements are evil when "replace conditional with polymorphism" could fix things.)